# Attribute table reformatting fields on programme close

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, string

I'm creating a density map using the graduated style in qgis.  The data is created from the points in polygon tool, this is then saved as an integer (not sure why the plugin doesn't automatically do this!) and displayed as a style.  When the edits are saved and editing mode closed all the field types are retained, so far so good, however, when I close QGIS completely and come to open it again the fields all return back to string format preventing the graduated style.

Is this just a glitch?

How do I get it to retain the field type?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using and exactly which tool did you use? There's a few _"points in polygon"_ tools such as `Count points in polygon`, `Count unique points in polygon`, `Random points inside polygons` etc.

Comment: 2.8.9 Wien.  Vector> Analysis Tools > Points in Polygon

Comment: That is a seriously outdated version (currently it's 2.18.11). So it _could_ be a bug. You could consider installing a newer version or a possible workaround could be create a new integer field after you run the tool, copy the values over and use this new field for your style.

Comment: @Joseph I think your comment is worth a full answer.

Comment: @AndreJ - Thanks but will wait for the original poster to confirm if it worked or not (something similar happened to me and my only solution was to wait for a new release) :)

Comment: I have put in a request for the version update with IT..It could take awhile